# drop with a specific shape into a quiet liquid water surface with mantaflow

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'd like to realize something like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLn1ErhxOPo

With the previous fluid simulator in Blender I was able to set a shape as a quiet basin of liquid, and another shape as a falling drop of the same liquid, and when the two meshes touched they interacted accordingly.

Is there a way to do that with mantaflow?

I'm very new to this simulator and I can not find proper documentation online yet. Any hint is well accepted!

Thank you, Riccardo.

Comment: For those who are interested I think I have found a way.
I just set a specific shape as an "inflow" emitter, then I animate the "emit" toggle as "on" at frame 1 and as "off" at frame 2.
In this way the emission stops instantly and the falling particles keep more or less the shape of the original geometry while falling into the basin of liquid which is made by setting as "fluid" "geometry" another rectangular mesh.
If you know better solutions I'm still open to learning more ;).

Comment: You can also set the specific shape (water droplet I suppose) to just an Inflow and Geometry.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with this method before but no points appeared inside the drop, maybe it was a scale problem?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe the simulation resolution was too low?

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do something like the video. I was able to do it on blender 2.8 but not with mantaflow.

After some tries I was able to get something similar (materials pending). The following images are from blender 2.90.1. If anything else needed let me know.

Water:

[image: Water1]

Ball (crosses the water object in 10 frames and has the scale of 1/3 of the water object)

[image: Ball]

CollisionBox part 1:

[image: CollisionBox1]

CollisionBox part 2:

[image: Box part 2]

The final result on frame 30:

[image: Final Result]